# Question on units of $\mathbb{Z}[i\sqrt{5}]$

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Find the units of $\mathbb{Z}[i\sqrt{5}] := \{a+bi\sqrt{5}:a,b
>  \in\mathbb{Z}\} \subseteq \mathbb{C}$.

By considering the modulus, we get that if $x + yi\sqrt{5} \in \mathbb{Z}[i\sqrt{5}]$ is invertible, we must have that $$\frac{1}{a^2 + 5b^2} \in \mathbb{Z}$$ But this would mean $a^2 + 5b^2 = 1$ which is only possible if $a = \pm 1$ and $b = 0$. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: No, you are perfectly right, except that is $a^ 2 + 5 b^ 2 = \pm 1$, where of course in this case $-1$ cannot occur.